# Problems with font src when building node package with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, node-modules

Going directly to the problem...

**lib.js code**

```
import DemoModule from './DemoModule.jsx';
import './styles/fonts/fonts.scss';
import './styles/styles.scss';

module.exports = {
    DemoModule: DemoModule,
};
```

**Fonts.scss**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Demo font';
    src: url('./demo-font.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

**Webpack code**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/lib.js',
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: './lib/',
        library: "libName",
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    },
    plugins: [
        ***
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
            { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json' },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'] },
            { test: /\.png$/, loader: 'url-loader' },
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.[ot]tf?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
            { test: /\.(eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

When i run **npm run build** this command compiles everything in lib directory, creates index.js and moves demo-font.ots in that directory too.

Direcotry looks like that

```
/lib
    index.js
    demo-font.ots
```

But when i use this package from **node_modules** in other project it looks for fonts like this www.abc.com/demo-font.ots and it's missing. Everything works, even css works, except fonts can't be loaded.

What I'm missing in this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Your SCSS file compiles with:

```
 src: url('./demo-font.otf') format('opentype');
```

So you are telling it to look in the current working directory for demo-font.otf

If the expectation is that the font is in the root of the domain, then that should work, however, if your font is somewhere else (like in the styles/fonts directory) then you will get a 404 not found.

Go to the developer tools (I use Chrome, so it's Ctrl+Shift+J) and check where your web application is expecting your font to be. Also "View Source" to check that, and then fix where relevant in the other project

Comment: When i'm using this package in other project it is placed in **node_modules/libName/lib** and font is located in **node_modules/libName/lib/demo-font.ots**

When i'm developing that package and run **npm run debug** command it lounches app and font is loaded also, but when I export it like node_module fonts is not working becouse of that path ./

Comment: How to tell to look for css resources in correct way? Web application is expecting that font should be in root /. But it's located in node_modules

Comment: @Mileris I explained that in my answer. In Chrome, CTRL+SHIFT+J to open developer tools, you will see resources loaded or not loaded and any javascript error. You can even inspect jquery, CSS etc. If it can't find the font, it will show you where it is looking for it, so it could give you, the programmer, an idea as to where to change your code